# How can I manually change image orientation?

Tags: 7, media

I manage a website with Drupal 7 where users can upload pictures from their mobile or from their desktop. I have configured Image Style with "autorotate" effect and most of the pictures are well displayed after styling.

But some are misoriented and I'd like to be able to manually change the picture orientation (or let the user do it).

Do you know a solution for this ?

Comment: Did you try https://www.drupal.org/project/exif_orientation?

Answer (score 0):

1 Read an image in JS from attached file https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

2 Use Lib for reading Exif data from jpg for autorotation as default option https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

3 Create controls for manual rotate image on canvas as manual tool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411991/html5-canvas-rotate-image

4 Send on server additional param with rotation value (for apply rotation to orig image on server side)
    OR
  Apply rotation on original size image on JS and send result on server as base64 code. Decode to binary data in server side and put it on disk.

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Simple Image Rotate](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_image_rotate) module.